# How to update and display data summed up from DB by BLoC pattern in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, bloc

**debt_dao.dart**

```
Future totalAmount() async {
    final db = await dbProvider.database;
    var result = await db.rawQuery("SELECT SUM(amount) as Total FROM $debtDetailsTable");
    var total = result[0]['Total'];
    print(total); // It prints expected value ex. 1400
    return total;
  }
```

**debt_repository.dart**

```
Future getTotalAmt() => debtDao.totalAmount();
```

**debt_bloc.dart**

```
getTotalAmount() async {
    await _debtRepository.getTotalAmt();
  }
```

I want to display the output here, while doing like below, it prints **null** only.

**debt_details.dart**

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    int _total;

    void calculateTotal() {
      _total = debtBloc.getTotalAmount();
    }

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(_total.toString()), // Total should show/updated here
      ),
```

And one more thing, I have a form whenever i add data in form, total should be updated.

**debt_form.dart**

```
saveDetails() async {
await debtBloc.getTotalAmount(); // Even this prints null only
}
```

As i am new to flutte struggling for long. Pls guide me in right way. Thanks in advance.

Comment: see https://medium.com/flutter-community/using-sqlite-in-flutter-187c1a82e8b

Comment: @pskink I have gone through the article. I guess i have to refactor/modify my widget code.

Comment: @pskink Even if i refactor my widget how can change my scaffold to streambuilder?

Comment: read some tutorials on `FutureBuilder` / `StreamBuilder`

Answer (score 0):

well I don't have any idea what pattern of BLOC did you use, but from my case I used the rxdart for using the BLOC pattern.
Assume that your DB is something like this

```
Future<double> totalAmount() async {
    final db = await dbProvider.database;
    var result = await db.rawQuery("SELECT SUM(amount) as Total FROM $debtDetailsTable");
    double total = result[0]['Total'];
    return total;
}
```

then in your bloc.dart

```
final BehaviorSubject<Future<double>> _totalAmount = BehaviorSubject<Future<double>>();
Observable<Future<double>> get totalAmount => _totalAmount.stream;

Future<double> getTotalAmount(){
    final totalAmount = totalAmount();
    _totalAmount.sink.add(totalAmount);
}
```

then in your main.dart

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
int _total;

bloc.getTotalAmount();

return Scaffold(
  appBar: StreamBuilder(stream: bloc.totalAmount, builder:(Buildcontext context, Asyncsnapshot<Future<double>> snapshot){
    if(!snapshot.hasdata){
        // return no data
    }

    return FutureBuilder(future: snapshot.data, builder:(Buildcontext context, Asyncsnapshot<double> amountSnapshot){
        if(!amountSnapshot.data){
            // return no data
        }

        return AppBar(
    title: Text(_total.toString()), // Total should show/updated here

    })
  }),
}
```

Hope this sample code can help you solve this problems

Comment: sorry for the late reply, I am using BLoC, Repository, Dao pattern.

```
final _debtController = StreamController<List<Debt>>.broadcast();

  get debts => _debtController.stream;

  /*DebtBloc({String query}) {
    getDebts(query: query);
  }*/

  getDebts({String query}) async {
    //sink is a way of adding data reactively to the stream
    //by registering a new event
    _debtController.sink.add(await _debtRepository.getAllDebts(query: query));
  }

```

Comment: And added total to stream like below 
getTotalAmount() async {
    final totalAmount = await _debtRepository.getTotalAmt();
    _debtController.sink.add(totalAmount);
  }